# Bloc confusion unable to tell event that changes has occurred

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have created this Homework bloc class where i get image from gallery and render that image to ui here in eventImageSink i pass event and with this _eventImageStream listen and add image to _stateImageSink and with the help of stateImageStream i am rendering image in my ui with Stream builder but.

```
enum GetImage { fetchImage }

class HomeworkBloc {
  final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  List<XFile>? selectedImages;
  List<XFile>? pickedImages;
  final _imageStateStreamController = StreamController<List<XFile>>.broadcast();

  StreamSink<List<XFile>> get _stateImageSink =>
      _imageStateStreamController.sink;

  Stream<List<XFile>> get stateImageStream =>
      _imageStateStreamController.stream;

  final _imageEventStreamController = StreamController<GetImage>();

  StreamSink<GetImage> get eventImageSink => _imageEventStreamController.sink;

  Stream<GetImage> get _eventImageStream => _imageEventStreamController.stream;

  HomeworkBloc() {
    _eventImageStream.listen((event) async {
      if (event == GetImage.fetchImage) {
        if (pickedImages != null) {
          _stateImageSink.add(pickedImages!);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    selectedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage(
        maxHeight: 800, maxWidth: 800, imageQuality: 100);
    List<XFile> temp = pickedImages ?? [];
    pickedImages = selectedImages;
    pickedImages?.addAll(temp);
  }
}
```

And i have user stream builder to load image like this

```
StreamBuilder<List<XFile>?>(
            stream: hB.stateImageStream,
            builder: (ctx, snapShot) {
              if (!snapShot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("no Data"),
                );
              } else if (snapShot.hasData) {
                return GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapShot.data!.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5),
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                      return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Image.file(File(snapShot.data![i].path)),
                              Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    height: 40,
                                    width: 40,
                                    color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
                                    child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            snapShot.data!.removeAt(i);
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever,
                                            color: Colors.white)),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ));
                    });
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ))
```

Now i am confused that how to pass event to eventImageStream that i have selected new images so render in Ui need some guidence here thanks.

Comment: why are you using the bloc this way, why not use `BlocBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder`, and why are you using streams and sinks instead of states and events? Maybe you should have a look at the [proper usage of bloc with flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

Comment: so to achieve what i want is it necessary to use BlocBuilder?

Comment: I don't know if you are intentionally using the bloc like this or if you are using it like this bcz you don't know about flutter_bloc package, but in all cases the recommended way to use bloc with flutter is with events and states, not with streams and sinks, unless you have to. Bloc was made as an abstraction over these concepts. And yes, with flutter_bloc it will be straightforward to handle events and update the state accordingly

Comment: well i didnt looked for flutter bloc package so i was using bloc with event and sink

Comment: thanks for your time i will learn flutter bloc  package